# Is there limitation of numbers of binding in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

Thanks to lots of people's help, I made an tkinter UI that drag/drop the cards.

However, I met another big problem. I want to bind the specific cards using line, but the binding does not work correctly when the number of line is larger than 8.

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
from PIL import ImageTk as itk

window = tk.Tk()
window.state('zoomed')

class DragAndDropArea(tk.Canvas):
    def __init__(self,master, **kwargs):
        tk.Canvas.__init__(self,master, **kwargs)
        self.active = None

        head = self.draw_card(200,200, 15,15, 'red1')
        eye_r = self.draw_card(220,200, 15,15, 'red2')
        eye_l = self.draw_card(180,200, 15,15, 'red3')

        neck = self.draw_card(200,250, 15,15, 'orange1')
        shoulder_r = self.draw_card(230,260, 15,15, 'orange2')
        shoulder_l = self.draw_card(170,260, 15,15, 'orange3')
        spine = self.draw_card(200,320, 15,15, 'orange4')
        pelvis_l = self.draw_card(180,390, 15,15, 'wheat1')
        pelvis_r = self.draw_card(220,390, 15,15, 'wheat2')

        elbow_r = self.draw_card(240,330, 15,15, 'yellow1')
        wrist_r = self.draw_card(240,400, 15,15, 'yellow2')
        fingertip_r = self.draw_card(250,430, 15,15, 'yellow3')

        elbow_l = self.draw_card(160,330, 15,15, 'green1')
        wrist_l = self.draw_card(160,400, 15,15, 'green2')
        fingertip_l = self.draw_card(150,430, 15,15, 'green3')

        knee_l = self.draw_card(180,490, 15,15, 'blue1')
        ankle_l = self.draw_card(180,560, 15,15, 'blue2')
        toe_l = self.draw_card(150,560, 15,15, 'blue3')
        knee_r = self.draw_card(220,490, 15,15, 'purple1')
        ankle_r = self.draw_card(220,560, 15,15, 'purple2')
        toe_r = self.draw_card(250,560, 15,15, 'purple3')

        self.bind_tention(head,eye_l)
        self.bind_tention(head,eye_r)
        self.bind_tention(head,neck)

        self.bind_tention(shoulder_l,neck)
        self.bind_tention(shoulder_r,neck)
        self.bind_tention(spine,neck)
        self.bind_tention(spine,pelvis_l)
        self.bind_tention(spine,pelvis_r)

        #self.bind_tention(shoulder_l,elbow_l)
        #self.bind_tention(elbow_l,wrist_l)
        #self.bind_tention(wrist_l,fingertip_l)
        #self.bind_tention(shoulder_r,elbow_r)
        #self.bind_tention(fingertip_r,wrist_r)
        #self.bind_tention(elbow_r,wrist_r)

        self.bind('<ButtonPress-1>', self.get_item)
        self.bind('<B1-Motion>',self.move_active)
        self.bind('<ButtonRelease-1>', self.set_none)

    def set_none(self,event):
        self.active = None
    def get_item(self,event):
        try:
            item =  self.find_withtag('current')
            print(item)
            self.active = item[0]
        except IndexError:
            pass
            #print('no item was clicked')
    def move_active(self,event):
        if self.active != None:
            coords = self.coords(self.active)
            width = coords[2] - coords[0] #x2-x1
            height= coords[1] - coords[3] #y1-y2
            position = coords[0],coords[1]#x1,y1

            x1 = event.x - width/2
            y1 = event.y - height/2
            x2 = event.x + width/2
            y2 = event.y + height/2

            self.coords(self.active, x1,y1, x2,y2)
            try:
                self.update_tention(self.active)
            except IndexError:
                pass
#                print('no tentions found')

    def update_tention(self, tag):
        tentions = self.find_withtag(f'card {tag}')
        for tention in tentions:
            bounded_cards = self.gettags(tention)
            card = bounded_cards[0][-1]
            card2= bounded_cards[1][-1]
            x1,y1 = self.get_mid_point(card)
            x2,y2 = self.get_mid_point(card2)
            self.coords(tention, x1,y1, x2,y2)
            self.lower(tention)

    def draw_card(self, x,y, width,height, color):
        x1,y1 = x,y
        x2,y2 = x+width,y+height
        reference = self.create_rectangle(x1,y1,x2,y2,
                                      fill = color)
        return reference
    def bind_tention(self, card, another_card):
        x1,y1 = self.get_mid_point(card)
        x2,y2 = self.get_mid_point(another_card)
        tag_I = f'card {card}'
        tag_II= f'card {another_card}'

        reference = self.create_line(x1,y1,x2,y2, fill='black',
                                 tags=(tag_I,tag_II))
        self.lower(reference)

    def bind_tention2(self, card, another_card):
        x1,y1 = self.get_mid_point(card)
        x2,y2 = self.get_mid_point(another_card)
        tag_I = f'card {card}'
        tag_II= f'card {another_card}'

        reference = self.create_line(x1,y1,x2,y2, fill='gray',
                                 tags=(tag_I,tag_II))
        self.lower(reference)

    def get_mid_point(self, card):

        width = coords[2] - coords[0] #x2-x1
    height= coords[1] - coords[3] #y1-y2
    position = coords[0],coords[1]#x1,y1

    mid_x = position[0] + width/2
    mid_y = position[1] - height/2

    return mid_x,mid_y
    def load_bg(self,img_route):
        img = itk.PhotoImage(file=img_route)
        bg= self.create_image(0,0,anchor = tk.NW,image=img)
        return bg
img_route = "C:/Users/ISDL_gram/Documents/hpe/3.png"
area = DragAndDropArea(window, bg='white')
#area.load_bg(img_route)
area.pack(fill='both',expand=1)
window.mainloop()
```

Here, I added # because the binding worked well for 8 tentions. When I drag the card related in #-tagged tention, it only works at initial loading and fails to update correctly. Now I am thinking update_tention works wrongly but I am having difficulty of understanding how the tags work.

I posts the picture how this works when I want to bind everything. Please teach me what to do and thank you very much.

[image]

Comment: Please provide [mre], otherwise Your code is too long

Comment: If there is a limit to the number of bindings, it's in the 10's or 100's of thousands if it exists at all.

Comment: Your code won't run, and is longer than it needs to be.

Comment: @BryanOakley Can you please tell me which point is redundant, at least briefly?

Comment: @EJSong: For one, the background image. For another, I don't think we need 20 rectangles. I can't tell, because your code won't run as posted.  Can the problem be reproduced with 19? 18? 10? Does the problem only occur with items that have lines attached to them? If the problem is with the number of bindings, do you need `update_tention`?

Comment: @BryanOakley This is for making human pose annotation tools and I need all 21 rectangles for my research purpose. And The problem occurs when I want to activate cards below 'pelvis_r'. And I am understanding that update_tention is for re-drawing lines between cards, so I think I need it but I am not sure since I am new to tkinter.

Comment: _You_ may need 21 rectangles, but do _we_ need them in order to reproduce the problem? The goal for the code in the question should strictly be for us to be able to reproduce the problem, and shouldn't be your whole program. We need just enough code to reproduce the problem, and no more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because you get the wrong card ID:

```
def update_tention(self, tag):
    tentions = self.find_withtag(f'card {tag}')
    for tention in tentions:
        bounded_cards = self.gettags(tention)
        card = bounded_cards[0][-1]  # get only the last digit, e.g. get "3" from "card 13"
        card2= bounded_cards[1][-1]  # get only the last digit
        x1,y1 = self.get_mid_point(card)
        x2,y2 = self.get_mid_point(card2)
        self.coords(tention, x1,y1, x2,y2)
        self.lower(tention)
```

It should be:

```
def update_tention(self, tag):
    tentions = self.find_withtag(f'card {tag}')
    for tention in tentions:
        bounded_cards = self.gettags(tention)
        card = bounded_cards[0].split()[-1]  # get last number, e.g. "13" from "card 13"
        card2= bounded_cards[1].split()[-1]  # get last number
        x1,y1 = self.get_mid_point(card)
        x2,y2 = self.get_mid_point(card2)
        self.coords(tention, x1,y1, x2,y2)
        self.lower(tention)
```

Comment: OH I should have splitted them ! You solved my problem completely and Thank you very much

Comment: Oh yes, I didnt think of this case [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67256220/13629335). Thanks